# hdfs dfs -setfacl fails on Azure Data Lake Store

Tags: azure, hdfs, azure-data-lake, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to change the Access Control List for a file located in an Azure Data Lake Store Gen 1 from an HDInsight 3.6 Cluster with the following command:

```
hdfs dfs -setfacl -m user:d7de0903-abcabc-44c1-8f1c-31311f5caa69:r-x adl://<myadls>.azuredatalakestore.net/user/pics/sammple.jpeg
```

It fails with:

```
-setfacl: Fatal internal error
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.HdiAdlFileSystem.shouldUseDaemonUserOrGroup(Unknown Source)
    at 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.HdiAdlFileSystem.getEffectiveAclEntries(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.HdiAdlFileSystem.modifyAclEntries(Unknown Source)
    at 
 org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.AclCommands$SetfaclCommand.processPath(AclCommands.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPaths(Command.java:317)
    at 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPathArgument(Command.java:289)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArgument(Command.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArguments(Command.java:255)
    at 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.FsCommand.processRawArguments(FsCommand.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:356)
```

As

```
 hdfs dfs -getfacl adl://<myadls>.azuredatalakestore.net/user/pics/sample.jpeg
```

works fine I am wondering if an ESP (Enterprise Security Package) Configuration is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below steps to set acls on Azure Data Lake Gen1 as follows.

**Before:** Getting acls of ADLS folder example and `user:bd04d6b3-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-3e30e6c99f3c:r--`

```
hdfs dfs -getfacl adl://<adlsname>.azuredatalakestore.net/clusters/example
```

[image]

**Set ACLs on ADLS:** Use the following command to set acls for specific user as follows:

```
hdfs dfs -setfacl -m user:bd04d6b3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx--3e30e6c99f3c:rwx adl://<adlsname>.azuredatalakestore.net/clusters/example
```

**After:** Now you can notice the acls are changed.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! That' s exactly what I did, but I am getting the error. Is your cluster configured with ESP?

Comment: It's not ESP cluster but you can configure same on the ESP Cluster as well.